# Stallings' fibration theorem - Explicit description

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Stallings' celebrated Fibration Theorem states that if a closed irreducible $3$-manifold $M$ admits a short exact sequence
\begin{equation}
1 \to N \to \pi_1(M) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 1,
\end{equation}
where $N$ is finitely generated, then $M$ fibers over $S^1$.

My question is that whether it is possible to give the exact form of $M$ if we already know that $N$ is a surface group. More precisely, assume there is a short exact sequence
\begin{equation}
1 \to \pi_1(S) \to \pi_1(M) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 1,
\end{equation}
where $S$ is a closed surface. Let $t \in \pi_1(M)$ be a preimage of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Conjugation with $t$ induces an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\pi_1(S)$ whose projection $[\varphi] \in Out(\pi_1(S))$ in the outer automorphism group does not depend on the choice of $t$. By the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer Theorem the extended mapping class group $MCG^{\pm}(S)$ is isomorphic to $Out(\pi_1(S))$. Let $f:S \to S$ be a homeomorphism so that $[f] \in MCG^{\pm}(S)$ corresponds to $[\varphi] \in Out(\pi_1(S))$ under the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer isomorphism. My question is whether $M$ is diffeomorphic to the mapping torus $T_f$ of $f:S \to S$. If this is true, does it just follow from Stallings' proof? Or, in case it is known but requires more work, is there a good reference for it?

More concretely, I am interested in the following situation (which might simplify things). If $M$ is a closed hyperbolic $3$-manifold so that $\pi_1(M)$ is (abstractly) isomorphic to the fundamental group $\pi_1(T_f)$ of a mapping torus, then $M$ is diffeomorphic to $T_f$. This is, of course, an easy consequence of the Geometrization Conjecture. However, I would like to know whether there is a proof of this fact that does *not* depend on the solution of the Geometrization Conjecture *nor* on Thurston's mapping torus theorem.

Comment: You certainly don't need to invoke Stallings here, since you already assumed the kernel is a surface group. Neither do you need to invoke the full strength of Perelman's geometrisation: Thurston proved that any mapping torus is geometrisable, and in particular in your case $T_f$ has to be hyperbolic. Mostow rigidity then implies that $M$ and $T_f$ are isometric. Alternatively, I think you can avoid geometry entirely using Waldhausen's theorem (see here:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242276/on-johanssons-theorem-on-homotopy-equivalences-of-3-manifolds).

Comment: I explicitely stated that I do not want to make use of Thurston's mapping torus result. But I will have a look at Waldhausen's theorem. Also, I would still be interested in the answer to my first question.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that you wanted to avoid Thurston. In that case, I think Waldhausen is probably what you want. If your "first question" is the case of a general surface-by-cyclic group, as opposed to the hyperbolic case, then I think this should also follow from Waldhausen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question ("is $M$ homeomorphic to $T_f$?") is answered in the affirmative by Theorem 2 of Stallings' paper *On fibering certain 3-manifolds".  You will also need his Theorem 1.  Here are the statements (slightly simplified).

**Theorem 1**: Suppose that $M$ is a compact connected three-manifold.  Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated normal subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ whose quotient group is $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then there is a surface $F$ properly embedded in $M$ so that $\Gamma = \pi_1(F)$.

**Theorem 2**: With hypotheses as in Theorem 1.  Suppose that $M$ is irreducible.  Suppose that $\Gamma$ is not $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M$ is a surface bundle over the circle, with $F$ isotopic to a fibre.

That is, your hypothesis on the short exact sequence (plus Theorem 1) gives the surface $F$.  Your hypothesis that the manifold $M$ is hyperbolic then gives the additional hypotheses of Theorem 2.

Note that Stallings does not cite Waldhausen. I suppose that this is because his situation is a very very simple case of a Haken hierarchy.  Once you have $F$ in your hands (and all the group theory hypotheses), it is "easy" to show that $M - F$ is homeomorphic to a product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if I am obsessing over tiny details, but I have the impression that what is stated is not yet enough to conclude what I want. Theorem 2 gives me that $M$ is *some* mapping torus $T_{f^\prime}$. However, I would like to conclude that $M$ is $T_f$ with the exact $f$ I described in my question. But I guess this should be clear if one of the following two statements is true (which I state in the next comment):

Comment: 1) Let $p:M \to S^1$ be the bundle projection given by Theorem 2. Then the induced map $\pi_1(p):\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ coincides (up to possibly precomposing with an automorphism of $\pi_1(M)$) with the given surjection $\pi_1(M) \to \mathbb{Z}$. I hope that this is an artefact of Stallings' proof. Is that correct?

Comment: 2) If $T_f$ and $T_{f^\prime}$ are mapping tori of homeomorphisms $f,f^\prime:S \to S$ such that their fundamental groups are (abstractly) isomorphic, then $T_f$ and $T_{f^\prime}$ are diffeomorphic. I only care about the case where the given mapping tori are aspherical. This should follow immediately from Thurston's mapping tori theorem and Mostow rigidity. Is there a proof that does *not* use Thurston's theorem?

Comment: Stallings proves (1) and Waldhausen proves (2).

Comment: Stallings builds the surface $F$ as follows.  We are given a homomorphism from $\pi_1(M)$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$.  We use this to find a surjection from $M$ to $S^1$ inducing the homomorphism.  (Idea: fix a triangulation of $M$ and deal with the skeleta in order of dimension.) Take a generic point of $S^1$ and take the preimage.  Homotope the map to improve the preimage until it is a connected $\pi_1$-injective surface.  This will be $F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you don't mind me asking, I have tiny follow up questions. When you say "Stallings proves (1)" do you mean that it is apparent from his proof, or is it also stated explicitly in some Theorem/Lemma? When you say "Waldhausen proves (2)" do you mean that it follows from Theorem 6.1 of his article *On irreducible 3-Manifolds which are sufficiently large* (if not, what is the reference)? If yes, does his condition "boundary-irreducible" allow empty boundary or not (if only non-empty boundary is allowed, do you apply the theorem to $T_f \setminus {\rm Disc}$)?

Comment: When I say "Stallings proves" I mean "You can find this in the second sentence of section two of his paper (on page 93)" A copy of the paper is available here: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/stallfib.pdf

Comment: When I say "Waldhausen proves" I mean "I only vaguely remember this".  Looking at the reference you suggest, in fact Corollary 6.5 is exactly what you want. Yes, boundary irreducible allows empty boundary.

Comment: Finally, if I have answered your question it is polite to accept my answer.  If I have not answered your question, but have at least been minimally helpful to you, then it is polite to upvote my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so patient. This was very helpful.